# jquery href returns undefined

Tags: jquery

I have this in my HTML

```
<a class="deleteLink" href="system/id">link</a>
```

Then using jQuery, I run this in $(document.ready(function()

```
alert($("a.deleteLink").attr("href"));
```

Which shows **system/id**

But running this:

```
alert($("a.deleteLink").href);
```

Shows **undefined**

If I add an Id to the a tag like this

```
<a id="myId" class="deleteLink" href="system/id">link</a>
```

Then

```
alert(myId.href);
```

shows **http://localhost/system/id** which is what I want to get from jQuery (so I can do something like

```
$.post($("a.deleteLink").href);
```

Can anyone help me with getting the full href value out of jQuery (1.2.6) please?

Comment: Well, your first href example works.. why do you want it to do with .href then?
Also the second part of your question does not seem to have anything to do with the first part. What is 'myId' (the variable)? A jQuery objet?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

$("...") returns a jQuery object (also called "wrapped set").  The wrapped set does not have a href attribute.  If you do this:

```
alert($("a.deleteLink")[0].href);
```

It should return the href attribute properly.  When you deal with "myId", you're dealing with a DOM element object.  Quite different to a wrapped set.  The index operator I used there is short for get(0) and that returns an element from the wrapped set.

Comment: Note: the element returned by either indexing objects in the wrapped set directly or using the .get() method will be a pure DOM object, which is why you are able to do "[element].href".

Answer (score 4):

Now I see what you want to do.

Try this:

```
alert( $("a.deleteLink")[0].href );
```